# Bootstrap Vue invalid feedback on input not computed

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I am working on a project that previous developer used Bootstrap Vue, the problem I have is with `b-form-invalid-feedback`.

Invalid feedback works once page is loaded, the reason for that is the docs provides [example does the same](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-group/) 
, now if you have a page with 10 input for a user to register and directly after he opens the page immediately the invalid feedback starts and shows errors in all fields for the user before he even starts writing his name.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap V4.3 CSS uses sibling selectors to show/hide valid/invalid feedback.

Wrap each input+feebdack components inside a div so that the other inputs/feedback are no longer siblings of the previous input(s).